# sed insert a line before the last string in a certain pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I have a config file with lines:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:sdfilter - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A sdfilter -j DROP
COMMIT
*nat
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:ds - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o dev -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o dev -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

and I am trying to insert a line `-I FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth2 -j DROP` between `*filter` and first `COMMIT` and only before the `COMMIT` in that pattern .so that resulting output looks like :

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:sdfilter - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A sdfilter -j DROP
-I FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth2 -j DROP   
COMMIT
*nat
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:ds - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o dev -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o dev -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

I have tried several ways and nearest solution I have reached is that I can append before every line in that pattern by using sed:

```
sed '/\*filter/,/COMMIT/i\FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth2 -j DROP' file
```

please suggest a pattern that I can insert only before last ("COMMIT") line in that filtered pattern ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` I can write,

```
/^\*filter$/{found++}
found && /COMMIT/ {
    print "-I FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth2 -j DROP";
    found=0
}
1
```

---

**What is does?**

- `/^\*filter$/{found++}` If current line is `*filter`, increament `found` by one.
- `found && /COMMIT/` If the current line has `COMMIT` and `filter` is non zero,

  - Print the string that we need to print and set the `found` to zero.
- `1` This is always true, in that case awk performs the default task to print the current line.

---

**Example**

```
$ awk '/^\*filter$/{found++} found && /COMMIT/{print "-I FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth2 -j DROP"; found=0} 1' file
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:sdfilter - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A sdfilter -j DROP
-I FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth2 -j DROP
COMMIT
*nat
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:ds - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o dev -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o dev -j MASQUERADE
-I FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth2 -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here it comes `sed` answer:

```
sed  -n -r '/COMMIT/{x; s/(\*filter.*)/\1\n-I FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth2 -j DROP/;  p; x;p; b end }; H; b; :end n; p; b end'  config_file | sed -e '1d'
```

Replace **--inserted text--** with text that will be appended before first 'COMMIT', plaese.

**Explanation**

- `H` appends current line to buffer
- `b <label>` - go to
- `: <label>` -  definition
- `b` - with no  simply ends current line processing
- `n` - go to next line
- `x` - swap pattern and hold buffer (there are only thoose two in `sed`)
- `p` - print pattern buffer on screen

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution Marek.. my only concern is that the sed pattern is adding new line at start of the file. Could you please correct it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/^\*filter/,/^COMMIT/{/^COMMIT/{i-I FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth2 -j DROP' -e ':a;n;ba}}' file
```

Find the range of lines between `*filter` and `COMMIT` then insert the required string before the line containing `COMMIT` and finally print all following lines.